# alert dialog box password verification before doing the next tasks

Tags: android

How can I verify the password in alertdialog box before doing the next tasks?

```
@Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        switch (v.getId()) {
            case R.id.insert_btn:
                new Thread(new Runnable() {
                    @Override
                    public void run() {
                        Looper.prepare();
                        makeHistory();
                        Looper.loop();
                    }
                }).start();
                break;
        }
    }

private void makeHistory(){

    AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
        builder.setTitle("PASSWORD");
        final EditText input = new EditText(this);
        input.setInputType(InputType.TYPE_CLASS_TEXT | 
    InputType.TYPE_TEXT_VARIATION_PASSWORD);
        builder.setView(input);
        builder.setPositiveButton("OK", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() 
        {
            @Override
            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                mPassword = input.getText().toString();
                // ****** stop proceeding to next task if password is incorrect *******
               if(mPassword == true) .....
            }
        });
        builder.setNegativeButton("Cancel", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                dialog.cancel();
                return;
            }
        });
        builder.show();
        // ***** next task here ******
        Log.d("Stop", "I dont want this to be print if password is incorrect");
}
```

Comment: Where do you have Password data ?

Comment: It is API call.

Comment: post your password to your api endpoint using a network call, verify the if the password is correct at the backend, then return proper response to the app side

Comment: My question, I want to stop the from executing next code, if the password is incorrect.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Depending on the response returned from your api call, check if the password is correct or not and then use a `if else` check to decide whether to execute **next tasks** . You have probably misplaced your next tasks contents after the alert dialog. See following example

```
if(mPassword.equals("password returned from server")){
 executeNextTasks();
} else {
// when wrong password execute something
}
```

inside `executeNextTasks` add whatever code you want to execute  when the password is correct

Answer (score 0):

Try with below code :

**REFERENCE CODE HERE :**

```
 builder.setPositiveButton("OK", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() 
        {
            @Override
            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                mPassword = input.getText().toString();

                //API call from Here 
                if (utils.haveNetworkConnection()) {
                    if (!input.getText().toString().isEmpty()) {
                        jsonRequestLogin(mPassword);

                    }else{
                        input.setError("Enter Password");     
                  }
                } else {
                    utils.showtoast("Internet Connection Not Available");
                }

            }
        });



 //API call here
 private void jsonRequestLogin(String mPassword) {

       if (code.equals("1")) {  //Correct Password
           //Go to next Activity
       }else{
          //In correct Password
       }

 }
```

Comment: My question is I want to stop executing // ***** next task here ******, if the password is incorrect.

Comment: Do you have your password before doing this  @Alvin

Comment: Where do you have your password that you want to compare with one you have editText "input" , Simply i wanna say whats your passoword ?

Answer (score 0):

I think you mean to say dont close dialog unless the password is correct. If so try this code

```
AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
builder.setTitle("PASSWORD");
builder.setView(input);
builder.setPositiveButton("OK", null);
builder.setNegativeButton("Cancel", null);

AlertDialog dialog = builder.create();
dialog.show();

dialog.getButton(DialogInterface.BUTTON_POSITIVE).setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View view) {
        if(!input.equals(password)){
           input.requestFocus();
           input.setError("Incorrect Password");
        }else{
          dialog.dismiss();   
          doNext();
        }
    }
});
```

then on Cancel button just call

```
dialog.dismiss
```

Comment: If the password is incorrect I don't want this to run:
// ***** next task here ******
        Log.d("Stop", "I dont want this to be print if password is incorrect");

Comment: Then you must call the next task inside the dialog not outside

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem is default `AlertDialog` behavior.  `DialogInterface.OnClickListener` will close the dialog anyway regardless of your code . So you need to prevent it . below is an example .

```
 AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(getActivity());
    builder.setMessage("Some random message");
    builder.setPositiveButton("Check",
            new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                    // Useless
                }
            });
    final AlertDialog dialog = builder.create();
    dialog.show();
    dialog.getButton(AlertDialog.BUTTON_POSITIVE).setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            // Do your stuff here 
        }
    });
```